# creating new instances of createjs object returns the same instance every time

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I'm have a strange problem. I have an object that extends createjs.Container like so:

```
(function() {
  var Door = function(label, color) {
    this.initialize(label, color);
  }
  var M = Door.prototype = new createjs.Container(); // inherit from Container
  M.Container_initialize = M.initialize;
  M.initialize = function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
  window.Door = Door;
}(window));
```

Whenever I try and create a new version of this object anywhere, the console.log output gives me the same object everytime. So if I do this:

```
var door1 = new Door();
var door2 = new Door();
```

I get console output of:

```
Door {id: 10, _matrix: c, children: Array[0], Container_initialize: function, initialize: function…}
Door {id: 10, _matrix: c, children: Array[0], Container_initialize: function, initialize: function…}
```

... both have the same ID.

I'm not sure what I have wrong here that would make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing one simple line from the M.initialize method:

```
this.Container_initialize();
```

Solved the problem!